# Finding several occurences of substring in string with Regex

Tags: java, regex

Consider the following string: 
`<spring:message code="common.about.team1" /> <br /> <br /> <spring:message code="common.about.team2" /> <br /> <br /> <spring:message code="common.about.team3" /></p>` 
What would be the corresponding Regular Expression that results in substrings in double quotes, that is: `common.about.team1`, `common.about.team2`, `common.about.team3` (preferably in Java, but not required)?

Comment: A great site to develop RegEx is https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be good looking into Pattern matching. However, I have included a snippet below that may help you solve your issue.

```
final static String str = "<spring:message code=\"common.about.team1\" />";
final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "\"(.+?)\"" );
final static Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( str );

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    while ( matcher.find() )
    {
        System.out.println( matcher.group( 1 ) );
    }
}
```

A good thing for the future would be to look at the following site and attempt to create your regex string:
http://regexr.com/3cse4

When you have your regex string working you can then look at implementing it and getting it to work with your application.

Output:

```
common.about.team1
common.about.team2
common.about.team3
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is another pattern which should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<spring:message code=\"common.about.team1\" /> <br /> <br /> <spring:message code=\"common.about.team2\" /> <br /> <br /> <spring:message code=\"common.about.team3\" /></p>";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    List<String> matches= new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(matches);
}
```

Output:

```
["common.about.team1", "common.about.team2", "common.about.team3"]
```